# Extracting Data from SQL Server Table within a Schema

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, rquery

I am having a hard time writing and extracting data from SQL Server in RStudio.
My database hierarchy is as follows:

- LDS

  - LDS

    - HIG

      - table_needed

I've tried:

```
ch <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "LDS")
q1<- sqlQuery(ch,("
         SELECT 
          AP_NAME,AP_Dep
          FROM [hig].[tb_pp_oz_CURR]
          Where AP_Dep <> 'K'|'C';
          ")
```

also

```
ch<- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "LDS")
q1<- sqlQuery(ch,("
         SELECT 
          AP_NAME,AP_Dep
          FROM in_schema("HIG","tb_pp_oz_CURR")
          Where AP_Dep <> 'K'|'C';
          ")
```

From what I've read, my problem is that my LDS Schema is set to default.  Is there a way to default my LDS schema? If not, is there a certain code I can use?

Comment: While I'm not certain of the fix for this, your second attempt is broken for two reasons: (1) `in_schema` is in `dbplyr`, not a SQL command, so it cannot be used directly within a SQL query; and (2) that second one is improperly quoted ... even if `in_schema` were acceptable SQL, you'd need to escape those double-quotes in its call. (That won't fix it here due to #1, but still.) Last point: (3) I didn't know it was possible to use an `odbc` connection (meant for `DBI`) in `RODBC` functions, does it really work?

Comment: (To the close-voter suggesting this is missing sufficient sample code, could you explain how that close-reason is applicable here? I understand that it's not really reproducible for those without access to *that* server, but I suggest the code is complete-enough to be reproducible in concept.)

Comment: Please include all `library` lines and error messages. Your code appears to conflate two packages where you run an `RODBC` method (`sqlQuery`) using an `odbc` connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I typically do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "LDS")
```

Then you can write your SQL as you normally would constructing the path to your schema as you would writing native SQL.

```
my_query <- 'SELECT 
          AP_NAME
         ,AP_Dep
          FROM [LDS].[LDS].[HIG].[tb_pp_oz_CURR]
          Where AP_Dep <> \'K\'|\'C\''
```

Then you could pass that to your connections with:

```
returned_data <- tbl(con, sql(my_query)) %>% collect()
```

The other option is that you use `dbplyr` and do something like

```
library(dbplyr)

returned_data <- tbl(con, in_schema("HIG", "tb_pp_oz_CURR")) %>% 
    filter(!AP_Dep %in% c("K", "C")) %>%
    select(AP_NAME, AP_Dept) %>%
    collect()
```